# Laravel отображение товаров на главное странице

Tags: php, laravel

Такая проблема, после удаления товара из админ панели, он удаляется из списка товаров в админке и в дата базе появляется дата удаления. Но при возврате на главную страницу с товарами возникает такая ошибка, кто знает почему?
Фото ошибки https://imgur.com/a/nWKQcT9
Если нужно предоставить еще код - скажите

```
card.blade.php - карточка книги
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 g-4">
    <div class="card h-100 reverse"> 
    <div class='img-box'> <img class="card-img" src="{{ Storage::url($offer->book->image) }}" alt="{{ $offer->book->__('name') }}"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="labels">
                @if($offer->book->isNew())
                    <span class="badge badge-success">@lang('main.properties.new')</span>
                @endif
                @if($offer->book->isRecommend())
                    <span class="badge badge-warning">@lang('main.properties.recommend')</span>
                @endif
                @if($offer->book->isHit())
                    <span class="badge badge-danger">@lang('main.properties.hit')</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $offer->book->__('name') }}</h5>
            <p class='card-text'><span>@lang('main.price')</span> {{ $offer->price }} {{ $currencySymbol }}</p>
            <form action="{{ route('basket-add', $offer) }}" method="POST">
                @if($offer->isAvailable())
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">@lang('main.add_to_basket')</button>
                @else
                    @lang('main.not_available')
                @endif
                <a href="{{ route('offer',
                    [isset($category) ? $category->code :
                    $offer->book->category->code, $offer->book->code, $offer->id]) }}"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                role="button">@lang('main.more')</a>
                @csrf
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На главной вы берёте все товары (и удаленные)?

Comment: Нужно только которые существуют

Comment: Насколько я понимаю под товаром понимается `book` и а в `offer` остался ключ на неё, но не получается подгрузить `book` из-за того что по умолчанию записи с softDelete не выдаются из запроса, вот вы и получаете ошибку. Вам нужно либо удалить ещё этот `offer` либо  поработать над запросом, который получает `offer`, что бы он не выдавал, те у которых удалена `book`. Если же под товаром всё таки понимается `offer`, то скорее всего где то в запросе на получение `offer` присутствует `withTrashed()`. Ещё как вариант можно просто в шаблоне проверять есть ли у `$offer->book`, но лучше запрос поправить